# Get last value based on a condition on ordered table in SQL

Tags: sql, rdbms, hana

I have a table representing product groups. Groups are defined by row number and their Type. Hence here we have 2 groups, the group is defined by the *Type A*, the *Type B* being components.

| Row number | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | B |
| 5 | B |

With just this data, **I need to find back the row number of the last preceeding *Type A* occurence** :

| Row number | Type | Row father |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 0 |
| 1 | B | 0 |
| 2 | B | 0 |
| 3 | A | 3 |
| 4 | B | 3 |
| 5 | B | 3 |

I can't find a way to get this. It's a sort of `lag()` or `first_value()` based on condition. Here I have 2 groups of 2 components, but I can have more groups with different sizes. The only thing that defines the group are the row number : every row number under *Type A* (so with *Type B*) is a child of the above *Type A*, until next *type A.*

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: This could be done with rank() in a cte or with a sub-query per line which would be less efficient but not all rdbms accept rank() and cte's, hence the importance of tagging with your rdbms.

Comment: This sounds like a usecase for the [HIERARCHY_LEVELED](https://help.sap.com/doc/e4fc5d26a38c4dc28802a3b87cd5eb10/2.0.06/en-US/SAP_HANA_Hierarchy_Developer_Guide_en.pdf) function

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired result by using a join in conjunction with a group-by.

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (ROW_NUMBER integer, TYPE varchar(1));
INSERT INTO test  VALUES (0, 'A');
INSERT INTO test  VALUES (1, 'B');
INSERT INTO test  VALUES (2, 'B');
INSERT INTO test  VALUES (3, 'A');
INSERT INTO test  VALUES (4, 'B');
INSERT INTO test  VALUES (5, 'B');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT T.*, MAX(A.ROW_NUMBER) AS ROW_FATHER
FROM TEST T
LEFT JOIN TEST A 
    ON A.TYPE = 'A' AND a.ROW_NUMBER <= T.ROW_NUMBER
GROUP BY T.ROW_NUMBER, T.TYPE
ORDER BY T.ROW_NUMBER
```

**Result**

[image]